# Generalization of Moore graphs -- not geometries

Tags: co.combinatorics, simplicial-complexes, hypergraph

I was thinking about the following problem: Suppose you have a $k$-uniform hyper graph (simplicial complex of dimension $k$) with a complete $(k-1)$-skeleton, and some form of regularity (e.g. every vertex appears in $d$ facets, or every $(k-1)$-simplex appears in $m$ facets).  Suppose that the smallest cycle under the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ boundary operator on the $k$-facets is of size D.  What can we say about the minimum number of vertices? Of facets?

This is a generalization of Moore graphs in a different direction than Moore geometries.  There a cycle is a closed path from vertex-to-facet-to-vertex; here it is a homological cycle (a more geometric interpretation, IMO).

Comment: What does *complete* mean?

Comment: Does k-*uniform* mean that each simplex is a face of a k-simplex?

Comment: $k$-uniform -- every hyperedge has $k$ vertices. Complete -- every $(k-1)$-face appears in some facet; alternatively every set of vertices of size $(k-1)$ appears as a subset of some hyperedge (of size $k$).

Comment: Note, the $k=3$ case is possibly related to this recent work: https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.07191, which is discussed on Gil Kalai's blog.